# syntax error near unexpected token `}' `

Tags: bash

I'm writing a shell script to make a new save file for the game risk of rain. I'm trying to make it so that each section of the unlocks that are available, such as achievements, monster logs, artifacts, etc. can either be added all at once to the file, or the user will be able to pick which ones they want added. I am new to writing shell scripts and I am not quite sure why I am getting the error ***syntax error near unexpected token `}'*** when I run what I have so far of my script. If anyone could explain to me as to why I am getting the error, how to fix it, and/or how to improve my script, it would be greatly appreciated. Also I am on Mac OS X if that matters. Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all

echo "This script takes ~/Library/Application Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini and backs it up to ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave. It generates a new Save.ini that is built to your specifications, unlocking all items and achievements or just the ones you choose, and replaces the existing Save.ini with the new one." >> ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/README.txt

mkdir ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave

cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave/

cd ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all

echo -n 'How would you like the new Save.ini to be built? Press 1 for all unlocks or 2 to customize.'
read text
if [ $text = "1" ]
then 
    {
        echo "[Achievement]" >> EOF1

        count=1

        while [ $count -lt 55 ]
        do
          echo "acheivement${count}=\"2\"" >> EOF2
          count=`expr $count + 1`
        done

        echo "[Record]" >> EOF3

        count=1

        while [ $count -lt 31 ]
        do
          echo "mons${count}=\"1\"" >> EOF4
          count=`expr $count + 1`
        done

        count=1

        while [ $count -lt 110 ]
        do
          echo "item${count}=\"1\"" >> EOF5
          count=`expr $count + 1`
        done

        count=1

        while [ $count -lt 10 ]
        do
          echo "artifact${count}=\"1\"" >> EOF6
          count=`expr $count + 1`
        done

        cat EOF1 EOF2 EOF3 EOF4 EOF5 EOF6 > Save.ini 

        rm EOF1 EOF2 EOF3 EOF4 EOF5 EOF6 

        cp -force ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/Save.ini ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini

        echo "Original Save.ini successfully overwritten."

        exit

    }   

elif [ $text = "2" ]; then
    {
        echo "You selected customize. Now we will build a custom Save.ini"
        echo -n "Press 1 if you want to unlock all achievements, press 2 to continue without unlocking all achievements."
        read text
        if [ $text = "1" ]; then 

            {
                echo "[Achievement]" >> EOF1
                count=1
                while [ $count -lt 55 ]
                do
                  echo "acheivement${count}=\"2\"" >> EOF2
                  count=`expr $count + 1`
                done

                echo "All achievements successfully unlocked."
                echo -n "Press 1 to make the Save.ini and replace the existing one with it and then exit, or press 2 to customize it further."
                read text
                if [ $text = "1" ]; then
                    {
                        cat EOF1 EOF2 > Save.ini
                        rm EOF1 EOF2
                        cp -force ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/Save.ini ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini
                        echo "Original Save.ini successfully overwritten."
                        exit
                    }

                elif [ $text = "2" ] then;
                    {
                        echo -n "Press 1 to unlock all monster logs, or press 2 to continue without unlocking all monster logs."
                        read text
                        if [ $text = "1" ]; then
                            {
                                echo "[Record]" >> EOF3 

                                count=1
                                while [ $count -lt 31 ]
                                do
                                  echo "mons${count}=\"1\"" >> EOF4
                                  count=`expr $count + 1`
                                done

                                echo "All achievements successfully unlocked."
                                echo -n "Press 1 to make the Save.ini and replace the existing one with it and then exit, or press 2 to customize it further."
                                read text
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You have an unbalanced `}`. Best way to solve this is either indent your code really well or use an editor for bash which supports you a bit (like VIM)

Comment: None of those braces are actually  necessary.

Comment: In shell, the braces are used for grouping I/O redirections, not normally just to group commands.  You have a stream of close braces at the end; the second of the four should either be a `fi` or needs a `fi` before it.  You are missing at least two more `fi`'s from the script.  I'll let you sort out how many of the braces you want to keep (none of them are necessary) — but your script has to make sense to shell without them too.

Comment: Pasting your code at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) will highlight the syntax errors.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Before deciding to write a script, you should have a basic understanding of the language in which you're writing. Even the most cursory reading of [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) or any [how-to pages](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) would have told you the correct syntax for an `if` statement.

Beyond that, you have a number of inefficiencies in your script. The backtick operator starts a subshell, a new instance of `bash`, so this is not necessarily something you want to be doing 110 times in a loop.

Here are a couple of your bigger problems fixed. I'd suggest looking into [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) to eliminate a lot of code repetition and conditional nesting.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all

echo "This script takes ~/Library/Application Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini and backs it up to ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave. It generates a new Save.ini that is built to your specifications, unlocking all items and achievements or just the ones you choose, and replaces the existing Save.ini with the new one." >> ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/README.txt

mkdir ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave

cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/originalSave/

cd ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all

read -n 1 -p 'How would you like the new Save.ini to be built? Press 1 for all unlocks or 2 to customize.' text
if [ $text = "1" ]
    then 
    echo "[Achievement]" > Save.ini
    for count in {1..54}; do
        echo "acheivement${count}=\"2\"" >> Save.ini
    done

    echo "[Record]" >> Save.ini
    for count in {1..30}; do
        echo "mons${count}=\"1\"" >> Save.ini
    done

    for count in {1..109}; do
        echo "item${count}=\"1\"" >> Save.ini
    done

    for count in {1..9}; do
        echo "artifact${count}=\"1\"" >> Save.ini
    done

    cp -force ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/Save.ini ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini
    echo "Original Save.ini successfully overwritten."
    exit

elif [ $text = "2" ]; then
    echo "You selected customize. Now we will build a custom Save.ini"
    read -n 1 -p "Press 1 if you want to unlock all achievements, press 2 to continue without unlocking all achievements." text
    if [ $text = "1" ]; then 
        echo "[Achievement]" > Save.ini
        for count in {1..54}; do
            echo "acheivement${count}=\"2\"" >> Save.ini
        done

        echo "All achievements successfully unlocked."
        read -n 1 -p "Press 1 to make the Save.ini and replace the existing one with it and then exit, or press 2 to customize it further." text
        if [ $text = "1" ]; then
            cp -force ~/Desktop/ror_save_unlock_all/Save.ini ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.riskofrain.riskofrain/Save.ini
            echo "Original Save.ini successfully overwritten."
            exit

        elif [ $text = "2" ]; then
            read -n 1 -p "Press 1 to unlock all monster logs, or press 2 to continue without unlocking all monster logs." text
            if [ $text = "1" ]; then
                echo "[Record]" >> Save.ini

                for count in {1..30}; do
                echo "mons${count}=\"1\"" >> Save.ini
                done

                echo "All monster logs successfully unlocked."
                read -n 1 -p "Press 1 to unlock all monster logs, or press 2 to continue without unlocking all monster logs." text
                if [ $text = "1" ]; then
                    #...
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script has some error:
- Line 93:  `elif [ $text = "2" ] then;` should change to  `elif [ $text = "2" ]; then`
- If command in bash must have fi to close a condition. You can refer to http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html
Hope this help